# Error running mvn package for jeromq: "Bind Cannot assign requested address: connect"

Tags: java, matlab, sockets, zeromq, jeromq

I want to send and receive data from Matlab and MetaTrader 5 on Windows 10.
According to [**this** post](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/269061-how-do-i-integrate-zeromq-library-with-matlab-i-want-my-matlab-program-to-be-a-subscriber-of-zeromq), JeroMQ is the easiest route to go:

- I cloned the repo from https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq
- I installed maven
- Then I went into the repository root and start building it
  using: mvn package, which produced the following error message:

```
 [ERROR] Failures:
 [ERROR] TestEvents.testEventConnectRetried:85 No event was received
 [ERROR] Errors:
 [ERROR] PollTest.testPollUdp:100 » Bind Cannot assign requested address: 
 connect
 [INFO]
 [ERROR] Tests run: 588, Failures: 1, Errors: 1, Skipped: 17
 [INFO]
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 04:48 min
 [INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-12T18:51:01+02:00
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project jeromq: There are test failures.
```

I tried to fix this by setting the IP configuration for the localhost to 127.0.0.1 according to these posts:

- https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/What-does-java-net-BindException-Cannot-assign-requested-address-mean
- [ZMQError: Cannot assign requested address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759394/zmqerror-cannot-assign-requested-address)

which did not fix the problem (same error message).

I think it is related to some IP settings, but I am new to socket communication. I have no experience in Java programming/debugging. Please help me to fix this, so the `.jar` file is built successfully and I can add it to my `javaclasspath` in Matlab.

**Otherwise:** Is there an (easy) alternative way to establish Matlab socket communication with other programs (e.g. via ZeroMQ)?

Comment: **[DUPLICATE]** Issue with installation package was already recorded on git: https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/issues/746

Comment: The package is running an unreasonable test.

Comment: Is there a workaround to skip this unreasonable test, so the package is built successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, to bypass the tests, you need to add some code to the pom.xml file which is at the main folder jeromq-masters.

So the part that I changed is below. You can compare with your own pom and change it according to it. Since a couple of days passed, I dont exactly remember the part that I added,but starting with "includes" must be the part that I added.

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
      <includes>
        <include>TestFail.java</include>
      </includes>
      <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
```

Then you need to recompile it with mvn package command.

This allowed me to compile the JAR file.

Comment: Was there anything else you needed to do to the pom.xml? Adding "includes" through "testFailureIgnore..." results in this error when running mvn package:


    `[Error]...\jeromq\src\main\java\org\zeromq\ZMQ.java:41: error: unexpected heading used: <H1>, 
    compared to implicit preceding heading: <H1>
    [ERROR]  * <h1>Contexts</h1>
    [ERROR]    ^`

I am trying this on windows openjdk version 13.0.2